# What does "catch" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does the word "catch" mean in this sentence?

> There must be a catch/incentive.

I looked it up in the dictionary the closest meaning to it seems to be

> a hidden problem or disadvantage in an apparently ideal situation

I am still unsure if that's the exact meaning.

Comment: I don't understand why you have catch/incentive in your example. Would you explain more about where you found the sentence?

Comment: Here is the story. One of our company competitors which did not have a general good rate in product review suddenly got 20 reviews all at the same day leading them to score higher. Our company CEO reacted with "There must be a catch/incentive"

Comment: Ah - that is interesting. So your CEO was thinking there were some [shady dealings](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shady-dealings) going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite right. *A catch* means a *hidden trap*. It shows that the situation isn't as good as it seems to be.

Answer (score 1):

"a catch" is similar to "too good to be true." For instance, a great job offer except that the pay is low or a free lunch but you have to sit through a boring presentation.

An incentive is a sweetener. To make the presentation more attractive, they're going to feed us lunch!